# How to configure Oracle traffic director for full site failover to have high availability?

Tags: oracle, replication, failover, proxy

I have two server systems, each server having both Apache Tomcat server (deployed web app) and Oracle 11g database server. The database on the two servers is synchronised by Oracle Data Guard for high availibility. Tomcat web server is running individually on each server system with no load balancing. One server acts as primary server and other server acts as redundant server.

Usually for any failure on primary server, I have to manually change the IP/Domain name to access the other server.

I have came across Oracle Traffic Director which may solve my isssue to switch any client request to redundant server in case of failure of primary server. Since I am new to Oracle Traffic Director, can anyone guide me to configure OTD for full site failover?

Comment: Oracle Traffic Director is a complicated, _licensed_, load balancer for web traffic. It does not balance database connections. Use Oracle Client (i.e. JDBC-Thick) with the proper tnsnames.ora configuration to also allow DB connections to route automatically to the active node.

Comment: I dont have to balance database connection. I just wanted to redirect all my http request from clients to other server in case of primary server is down.

Comment: http requests, or database connections? http requests will require a load balancer of some kind. database connection failover will require Oracle Client and a proper tnsnames.ora configuration. a proper setup would also cluster the tomcat servers - then you could direct http traffic to whichever tomcat server is up (or both) with the tomcat servers sharing user session information, and tomcat would automatically connect to the proper primary database instance. there are a variety of open source load balancers out there that would be much simpler to install and maintain than OTD.

Answer (score 0):

For a true HA architecture, HTTP traffic must be balanced with a front-end load balancer on a separate host. See here for a list of open source balancers (any of which would be simpler and cheaper to implement than OTD):

- https://geekflare.com/open-source-load-balancer/

Oracle DB connections should be configured for high availability failover as described here (use the architecture that best fits your technology stack):

- https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/availability/client-failover-2280805.pdf

An example of how to implement tomcat's native clustering to compliment the load balancing can be found here on my blog site:

- https://pmdba.files.wordpress.com/2019/09/ha-oracle-ords-apex-with-http-header-authentication.pdf